# "alias method chain" in Bash or Zsh

Tags: bash, alias, zsh

This is (or *was*, at least) a common pattern in Ruby, but I can't figure out how to do it in Zsh or Bash.

Let's suppose I have a shell function called "whoosiwhatsit", and I want to override it in a specific project, while still keeping the original available under a different name.

If I didn't know better, I might try creating an alias to point to whoosiwhatsit, and then create a new "whoosiwhatsit" function that uses the alias.  Of course that work, since the alias will refer to the new function instead.

Is there any way to accomplish what I'm talking about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aliases are pretty weak. You can do this with functions though. Consider the following tools:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

PS4=':${#FUNCNAME[@]}:${BASH_SOURCE}:$LINENO+'

rename_function() {
  local orig_definition new_definition new_name retval
  retval=$1; shift
  orig_definition=$(declare -f "$1") || return 1
  new_name="${1}_"
  while declare -f "$new_name" >/dev/null 2>&1; do
    new_name+="_"
  done
  new_definition=${orig_definition/"$1"/"$new_name"}
  eval "$new_definition" || return
  unset -f "$orig_definition"
  printf -v "$retval" %s "$new_name"
}

# usage: shadow_function target_name shadowing_func [...]
# ...replaces target_name with a function which will call:
# shadowing_func target_renamed_to_this number_of_args_in_[...] [...] "$@"
shadow_function() {
  local shadowed_func eval_code shadowed_name shadowing_func shadowed_func_renamed
  shadowed_name=$1; shift
  shadowing_func=$1; shift
  rename_function shadowed_func_renamed "$shadowed_name" || return
  if (( $# )); then printf -v const_args '%q ' "$@"; else const_args=''; fi
  printf -v eval_code '%q() { %q %q %s "$@"; }' \
    "$shadowed_name" "$shadowing_func" "$shadowed_func_renamed" "$# $const_args" 
  eval "$eval_code"
}
```

...and the following example application of those tools:

```
whoosiwhatsit() { echo "This is the original implementation"; }

override_in_directory() {
  local shadowed_func=$1; shift
  local override_cmd_len=$1; shift
  local override_dir=$1; shift
  local -a override_cmd=( )
  local i
  for (( i=1; i<override_cmd_len; i++)); do : "$1"
    override_cmd+=( "$1" ); shift
  done
  : PWD="$PWD" override_dir="$override_dir" shadowed_func="$shadowed_func"
  : override_args "${override_args[@]}"
  if [[ $PWD = $override_dir || $PWD = $override_dir/* ]]; then
      [[ $- = *x* ]] && declare -f shadowed_func >&2 # if in debugging mode
      "${override_cmd[@]}"
  else
      "$shadowed_func" "$@"
  fi
}

ask_the_user_first() {
  local shadowed_func=$1; shift;
  shift # ignore static-argument-count parameter
  if [[ -t 0 ]]; then
    read -r -p "Press ctrl+c if you are unsure, or enter if you are"
  fi
  "$shadowed_func" "$@"
}

shadow_function whoosiwhatsit ask_the_user_first

shadow_function whoosiwhatsit \
  override_in_directory /tmp echo "Not in the /tmp!!!"

shadow_function whoosiwhatsit \
  override_in_directory /home echo "Don't try this at home"
```

The end result is a `whoosiwhatsit` function that asks the user before it does anything when its stdin is a TTY, and aborts (with different messages) when run under either `/tmp` or `/home`.

---

That said, I don't condone this practice. Consider the above provided as an intellectual exercise. :)

Comment: Intellectual exercises are worthy answers!  Such things help us know what the real cost/benefit ratio is likely to be, and are much more useful than just "don't do that!".

Comment: To be fair, the above could have been a little shorter if it didn't include debugging tools (all the `: foo="$foo"` lines to log variable contents, the `declare -f` in the `[[ $- = *x* ]]` case, etc) -- but the debugging tools wouldn't have been there if I hadn't needed them to get it right. :)

Answer (score 2):

In bash, there is a built-in variable called `BASH_ALIASES` that is an associative array containing the current aliases.  The semantics are a bit inconsistent when you update it (RTM!) but if you restrict yourself to reading `BASH_ALIASES`, you should be able to write yourself a shell function that implements alias chaining.

Answer (score 1):

It's common and well supported to create a single level of overrides through functions that optionally invoke their overridden builtin or command:

```
# Make all cd commands auto-exit on failure
cd() { builtin cd "$@" || exit; }

# Make all ssh commands verbose
ssh() { command ssh -vv "$@"; }
```

It doesn't chain beyond the one link, but it's completely POSIX and often works better in practice than trying to write Ruby in Bash.